# HTML Canvas clip area - Context restore?

Tags: image, html, canvas, clipping, clip

Am trying to set a "dirty zone" on my canvas to prevent the repainting of unmoved items (background image, static items, etc.)
i.e. only the background painted behind a moving player needs to be redrawn

EDIT: As suggested, here's the jsfiddle of it
http://jsfiddle.net/7kbzj/3/

The "update" method doesn't work out there, so it's moveSprite() you can get run by clicking the "move sprite" link... Basically, the clipping zone shouldmove by 10px to the right each time you click. Clipping mask stays at initial position, only the re-paint occurs. Weird o_O

So as I init my canvas, once the background is painted, set I use the ctx.save() method:

```
function init() {
    canvas = document.getElementById('kCanvas');
    ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');  

    ctx.fillStyle = "rgb(0,128,0)";
    ctx.fillRect (0,0,320,240);

    ctx.save();

    setInterval(function () { update(); }, tpf);
}
```

In order to see the clipping works, I draw a different color background (blue one) in the area that I wanted clipped... the result is bad, only the first clipped area is painted blue :(

```
function update() {
    setDirtyArea(x,y,w+1,h)

    ctx.fillStyle = "rgb(0,0,128)";
    ctx.fillRect (0,0,320,240);

    x++;

    // paint image
    ctx.clearRect(x,y,w,h);
    ctx.drawImage(imageObj, x, y);
```

}

```
function setDirtyArea(x,y,w,h) {
   ctx.restore();   
   // define new dirty zone
   ctx.beginPath();
   ctx.rect(x, y, w, h);
   ctx.clip();
}
```

I'd love to se the blue zone propagate itself towards the right of the screen... please help, I don't understand what's wrong!
Thanks,
J.

Comment: Instead of dealing with clipping, it might be easier just to use multiple canvases (CSS z-index helps!). This allows you to avoid clipping altogether. By the way, it might be cool if you could set up a concrete demo to jsfiddle or a similar service.

Comment: Thanks for the advice... Indeed, here's a jsfiddle of it!
http://jsfiddle.net/7kbzj/3/

BTW, jsfiddle can't register intervals, so I added a btn that calls moveSprite(), which is the same...

For he multi-canvas, yes, that could do. But then you would repaint stuff that's not moved. As it's meant to run on mobile devices, clipping is needed as it should be huge performance saver.

Comment: I moved save/restore elsewhere. Take a look at it now, http://jsfiddle.net/7kbzj/4/ . You might still need to tweak something. I'm guessing the "save" at init doesn't get triggered properly (canvas isn't ready yet?). Make sure you execute it after the document has loaded properly (another possible fix).

Comment: Oh right! Seems like .restore() pops the last state out of the stack... which would explain why .save() needs to be called every time. Great thanks man.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to wrap the actual drawing and clipping of the box with the save and restore methods. and include the closePath method. I have modified your fiddle to work the way I believe you are trying to make it.

http://jsfiddle.net/jaredwilli/7kbzj/7/

```
ctx.save(); // save the context
    // define new dirty zone
    ctx.beginPath();
        ctx.rect(x, y, w, h);
        ctx.clip();

ctx.restore(); // restore the context
```

I also have learned that using save and restore can get really complex, and confusing to know which context your in. It came up with a pretty huge canvas app im working on, and i found that indenting your canvas code helps immensely. Especially the save/restores. I have even decided it should be considered a best practice, so the more people who know and do it the better.

Hope this helps.

Comment: I actually teach canvas, and I will definitely teach this way to indent. This is awesome.